# How can one see that the Hydrogen atom has $SO(4)$ symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory, hydrogen, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

1. For solving hydrogen atom energy level by $SO(4)$ symmetry, where does the symmetry come from?
2. How can one see it directly from the Hamiltonian?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116244/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runge-lenz-vector . A derivation of $SO(4)$ symmetry is e.g. given in G. 't Hooft, [_Introduction to Lie Groups in Physics_](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg.html), lecture notes, chapter 9. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/lieg07.pdf).

Comment: After studying the answers and comments here, I think (1) this is not really a quantum mechanics question. Maybe I should study why Kepler problem has SO(4) symmetry.  (2) People have studied the classical Kepler problem should be able to see the so(4) symmetry from the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Of course the $SO(4)$ symmetry is preserved in the classical limit. Note however that computationally, the proof of $SO(4)$ symmetry is a order of magnitude harder in the quantum mechanical problem than in the classical problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Hamiltonian for the hydrogen atom
$$
H = \frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m} - \frac{k}{r}
$$
describes an electron in a central $1/r$ potential. This has the same form as the Kepler problem, and the symmetries are similar. There is an obvious $SO(3)$ generated by the angular momentum $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p}$. In other words, the components of $\mathbf{L}$ satisfy
$$
[L_i,L_j] = i \hbar \epsilon_{ijk}L_k .
$$
A more subtle symmetry is given by the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector
$$
\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{2m} ( \mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{L} - \mathbf{L} \times \mathbf{p}) - k \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r}.
$$
The commutation relations involving $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are
$$
[L_i,A_j] = i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk} A_k \\
[A_i,A_j] = -i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{2H}{m} L_k .
$$
Up to the normalization of $\mathbf{L}$ this is the commutation relations of $SO(4)$. (Here I assume that we are considering a bound state whose energy $E$ is negative. If $E>0$ the above relation generate a non-compact $SO(3,1)$ symmetry.)

Furthermore, both $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ commute with the Hamiltonian,
$$
[H,L_i] = 0, \qquad
[H,A_i] = 0
$$
showing that they indeed generate symmetries of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: See also this [blog post](http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/hydrogen-atom-and-so4-symmetry.html) by Lubos Motl.

Comment: Minor remark : The dynamical symmetry is $SO(4)$ for bound states ($H <0$), and $SO(3,1)$ for excited states ($H>0$). There is a very interesting discussion in "Robert Gilmore, Lie Groups, Physics and Geometry,  Cambridge", Chapter $14$, Hydrogenic atoms.

Comment: @Trimok: Looks like a very interesting reference, thanks. I implicitly assumed that $H<0$, otherwise the $[A,A]$ commutator changes sign and the symmetry is non-compact.

Comment: thanks. My question was that how can one see the physical picture behind these. what's the corresponding SO(4) rotation on H?  why is there a 4d sphere involved?

Comment: @ahala: $L_i$ and $A_i$ commute with $H$, so the $SO(4)$ rotations don't act on $H$. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Lenz#Rotational_symmetry_in_four_dimensions) has a discussion about making the $SO(4)$ symmetry manifest in the Kepler problem by mapping it to a free particle moving on a three-sphere, but I don't really think it makes the physics behind it clearer.

Comment: @ahala: For some physical intuition one can note that the energy of an eigenstate of the hydrogen atom only depends on the principal quantum number $n$, but not on the angular momentum $l$ or the magnetic quantum number $m$. Such a degeneracy is often related to additional symmetries. Of course, this doesn't tell you what the relevant symmetry should be.

Comment: @ahala : In the book of Gilmore (see previous comment), there is a discussion. One notices, that, in the momentum space, which is in a plane, momenta obey a circle equation. The next observation is that a circle in $R^3$ is promoted to a circle in $S^3$ (included in $R^4$), by a projective transformation, which is a stereographic projection, which is invertible and preserve angles (conformal), so that circles in $R^3$ are in one-to-one correspondence with circles in $S^3$. Now, obviously, $SO(4)$ is a symmetry of $S^3$, so it is also a hidden (dynamical) symmetry of the hydrogenoid atom.

Answer (score 3):

It's because there is another vector quantity $A_i$ conserved in addition to the angular momentum $L_i$. Furthermore, the commutation relations of $A_i$'s and $L_i$'s are those of $SO(4)$. See for instance this reference : http://hep.uchicago.edu/~rosner/p342/projs/weinberg.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to complement the answers above. 
For (1) $so(4) = so(3) \times so(3)$, one $so(3)$ is from the geometric 3D symmetry of the Hamiltonian, and the other $so(3)$ is from the potential term of  $\frac{k}{r}$.

For (2). the second $so(3)$ symmetry is a dynamic symmetry and only holds when potential term is inversely proportional to $r$. One has to do the calculation to find it.