# Energy of central potential in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, symmetry, schroedinger-equation, spherical-harmonics

A hydrogen atom (Coulomb potential) has energy that only depends on $n$ (if we ignore other effects like spin-orbit coupling). In general (not necessarily Coulomb, can be any V), does $E$ depend on both $\ell$ and $n$ (since the radial equation has both $n$ and $\ell$)? What about $m$? Since $m$ doesn't appear in the radial equation, does it mean that energy does not depend on $m$?

Comment: At higher order the energy does depend on m and manifests itself as fine-structure (the spin-orbit coupling term anyway), and at even higher order in the hyperfine structure.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116244/2451

Comment: But there is m because we use perturbation theory to 'add' those higher order effects, right? I wanna ask given a potential $V(r,\phi,\theta)$ in general, what does the energy depend by just solving the Schrodinger Equation (and ignore other higher effects that may appear in reality)?

Answer (score 2):

The wave function of the hydrogen atom $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$ is a product of the radial part, the angular part and azimuthal term
$$
\psi_{n,\ell,m}(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi).
$$
The radial part $R(r)$ obeys Laguerre polynomials or,
$$
R_{n\ell}(r) = Ae^{-\rho/2}\rho^\ell L^{2\ell+1}_{n-\ell-1},~ \rho = \frac{2r}{na_0},
$$
and $A$ is a complicated constant, The angular part $\Theta(\theta)$ is given by spherical harmonics $Y^\ell_m(\theta,\phi)$ and the azimuthal is $\Phi(\phi) = e^{im\phi}$, where $m$ is the projection of the angular momentum on the $z$ axis.

Answer (score 1):

The  energy levels of the bound-states of a hydrogen atom only depend on the radial quantum number  **n** .

This is a special property of a  **(1/r)** type of  *interaction potential* .

For a general central potential, **V (r )** the quantized energy levels of a bound-state  can  depend on both  **n** and **l** values.

The property  that the energy levels of a hydrogen atom only depend on  **n** , and not on **l**  and **m**, points to the feature  that    the energy spectrum of a hydrogen atom is **highly degenerate**.

By degeneracy of a state we mean that   there are *many different states  of the system* which possess the same   *energy eigen value*.

For a given value of  **l** , there are   **(2l+1)**  different allowed values of  **m**  (i.e.,-l , -l+1 , ...0  1 ,2, (l-1) ,+l ).

Likewise, for a given value of  **n**, there are n  different allowed values   of **l** (i.e. 0 , 1, 2, ,(n-1)).

Now, all states possessing the same value of  **n**  have the same energy (i.e., they are *degenerate* )

The total number of degenerate states for  a given value of  **n** comes out to be   **n^2.**

The above *degeneracy  gets lifted* if the interaction potential has such terms which can give rise to splitting of the degenerate states.

A common example is placing the atom in a magnetic field which splits the different m -states. or spin-orbit interaction term in the potential .