# Degeneracy of Hamiltonian for Hydrogen Atom (Coulomb Problem)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hamiltonian, hydrogen, laplace-runge-lenz-vector

It can be proven that the commutation relations $$\Big[ N,H\Big]=0$$   $$\Big[ L,H\Big]=0$$  $$\Big[ N,L^2\Big]  \neq 0$$ Where $N$ is the Runge-Lenz vector. I'm wondering if it  is possible to write down the features of the spectrum of $H$ using the commutation relations?

Comment: yes, Pauli did that in 1925. Google "hydrogen atom algebraic solution"

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116244/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89654/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242035/2451 and links therein.